# TypeScript Duplicate Identifer

Tags: typescript

In the following TypeScript fragment

```
export class Customer {
    firstName : string = "";
    lastName : string = "";

    fullName : string = "";
    constructor(public firstName, public lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
   }
 }
```

Why do I get an error in firstName  and lastName in the constructor, the error is

```
 [ts] Duplicate identifier 'firstName'.
 [ts] Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 
'firstName' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'any'.
```

This was supposed to be a fragment that was error free.

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public firstName` in the constructor implicitly makes a `firstName` field and initializes it.

Therefore, making another field with the same name is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You basically defined your `firstName` and `lastName` property twice.

When you pass parameters to constructor and use `public` you are essentially creating a `public` parameter.

When you have the following class defination,

```
class Customer {
   constructor(public firstName: string) { }
}
```

it is equal to

```
class Customer {
  public string firstName;

  constructor(firstName: string) { 
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
}
```

Update your code as follows:

```
export class Customer {
    fullName : string = "";

    constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should delete the initializer too.